# 2D array : append value in 2D array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have a JSON object

```
 "methodSet":[{"num":1,"methodName":1,"methodStatus":1},
 {"num":2,"methodName":2,"methodStatus":1}]
```

I need to put the methodName and methodStatus into MethodClass array.

Based from the below code, I always get the last value for my MethodClass [2][1]. The expected result that I want is [1][1],[2][1]. Can I have any idea how I can accumulate the value for my methodSet? What are the method that I can use to Append my 2D array?

```
JSONArray arr=(JSONArray)obj.get("methodSet");
int lengtharr = arr.length();
    if (arr != null) {
        JSONObject objMethod1;
        String MethodName, MethodStatus;
        for (Object o1 : arr) {
            objMethod1 = (JSONObject) o1;
            MethodName = String.valueOf(objMethod1.get("methodName"));
            MethodStatus = String.valueOf(objMethod1.get("methodStatus"));

            int resultMethodName = Integer.parseInt(MethodName);    
            int resultMethodStatus = Integer.parseInt(MethodStatus);

            for (int j = 0; j < lengtharr; j++) {
                        methodSetFinal[i][j] = new MethodClass();
                        methodSetFinal[i][j].setmethodName(resultMethodName);
                        methodSetFinal[i][j].setmethodStatus(resultMethodStatus);

                        methodSet [i][j] = methodSetFinal [i][j];
            }
        }
}
```

MethodClass Code:

```
public class MethodClass {
private int methodName;
private int methodStatus;

public MethodClass() {
methodName = 0;
methodStatus = 0;
}

public int getmethodName() {
return methodName;
}
public int getmethodStatus() {
return methodStatus;
}

public void setmethodName(int i) {
this.methodName = i;
}

public void setmethodStatus(int status) {
this.methodStatus = status;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please add the complete code of your class?

Comment: `i` isn't defined here. And why do you have a 2D array anyway? Seems like you should have a 1D array (or `List`), where each element is a `MethodClass` instance. Not sure why you have two `MethodClass`es for each `JSONObject`. They are just duplicates of each other.

Comment: @ZainUlAbideen added the MethodClass code

Comment: @MichaelYaworski The program can receive either [1][1] or [1][1],[2][1] . That is the reason why it need to have 2D array. 
Index for the MethodSet should be [0][0],[0][1]

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the concept of Objects. The `MethodClass` holds two pieces of data (`methodName` and `methodStatus`). So having an array of `MethodClass` instances will give you the `[1][1], [2][1]` thing you're looking for. You would have `MethodClass`, `MethodClass` where the first holds `methodName = 1`, `methodStatus = 1` and the second which holds `methodName = 2`, `methodStatus = 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a 2D array, a simple array is enough and one `for` loop is enough

```
JSONArray arr=(JSONArray)obj.get("methodSet");
if (arr != null) {
    int lengtharr = arr.length();
    MethodClass[] methodSetFinal = new MethodClass[lengtharr];
    JSONObject objMethod1;
    String MethodName, MethodStatus;
    int index = 0;
    for (Object o1 : arr) {
        objMethod1 = (JSONObject) o1;
        MethodName = String.valueOf(objMethod1.get("methodName"));
        MethodStatus = String.valueOf(objMethod1.get("methodStatus"));

        int resultMethodName = Integer.parseInt(MethodName);    
        int resultMethodStatus = Integer.parseInt(MethodStatus);
        MethodClass methodClass = new MethodClass(); 
        //A constructor in your model class that takes two parameters would have been nice
        methodClass.setmethodName(resultMethodName);
        methodClass.setmethodStatus(resultMethodStatus);
        methodSetFinal[index] = methodClass;
        index++;
    }
}
```

I haven't checked your json related code and simply assumes it is correct.